# Populating TableView cells using GCD

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

I'm new to working with GCD and I'm struggling to understand if what I'm doing here is the correct way to do things.

When I configure a cell, I want to extract a URL from a managed object and then dispatch a block to GCD to pull down the thumbnail image that resides at the URL.

Once the image downloads I am dispatching another block within the first block that puts the downloaded thumbnail into the cell.

When the table appears on screen I expect to see an activity spinner in each cell's thumbnail, with the thumbnail subsequently replaces with an actual image once it's finished downloading.

What actually happens is that the cells appear within the TableView and I don't see the spinner. If I click on a cell however, the image appears suddenly. Likewise if I navigate away from that view and then display it again. Additionally when I scroll the TableView up and down, something very strange happens - the thumbnails seem to "repeat" and then redownload as I scroll.

I'm sorry if that's a little hard to explain, but I don't know how best to describe what I'm seeing.

I'd appreciate if anyone could take a look at the code and perhaps give some suggestions as to what might be going wrong:

```
 if([managedObject isKindOfClass:[Photo class]])
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    [cell.imageView addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];

    Photo *photo = (Photo *)managedObject;

    NSString *URLString = photo.thumbnailURL;

    dispatch_queue_t callerQueue = dispatch_get_current_queue();
    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Thumb downloader", NULL);

    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
       NSData *imageData = [FlickrFetcher imageDataForPhotoWithURLString:URLString];  
        dispatch_async(callerQueue, ^{
            UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [spinner stopAnimating];
            cell.imageView.image = thumbImage;
            [cell.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
        });
    });
    dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
}
return cell;
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommned creating a new queue for your downloader use a global queue like dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) also instead of using the "callerQueue" use the main thread with dispatch_get_main_queue()

Comment: Does the FlickrFetcher block the current thread until the download is finished?

Comment: I had a very similar code and also was not working. I fixed by replacing [cell.imageView setNeedsDisplay] for [cell setNeedsLayout]. I also get the reference to the cell again using [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; in case current reference was reused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not directly access a cell after background loading of data (in this case image).  If it scrolls off screen before you load the data, it's invalid.  You should set the mechanisms off on their data loading way, and when it returns invoke `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation]`.

Comment: When you say "You should set the mechanisms off on their data loading way", do you mean that when the cell is initially configured I should send fire off the dispatch queue and then when it returns, call the method you detail to reload the cell?

Comment: there are many decisions about when and what data to load - you can make those depending on your situation, but if you don't have the data when the cell is being "painted", you should put up a default, even better if the model just feeds it to you. when new data arrives, tell the table to reload all or part of its data

Comment: Thanks. Would a UIActivitySpinner count as an acceptable default until the proper data is there?

Also in terms of thumbnails, would it be generally acceptable to cache them in Core Data or is that behaviour that is frowned upon?

Comment: multiple activity spinners can get annoying (imho), and you need to be careful about stopping them when a cell goes off screen and gets reused, whereas a "blank" image is easier to handle - core data is fine to cache information in - store the core data file in the caches directory so it isn't backed up when device is sync'd

Comment: Once I have the data, won't I need to get a fresh NSManagedObjectContext so that I can put the data into Core Data and then sync the context back to the main thread so it will see the changes?

Comment: Actually that does it just fine - I dispatch the block and when it updates in core data, it magically appears on screen. Sorted!

Answer (score 1):

> `[cell.imageView addSubview:spinner];`

The above line doesn't smell like it would work.  try `[cell.contentView addSubview:spinner];`  instead.  you will likely have to change the spinner's frame.origin to get it in the right place.

> the thumbnails seem to "repeat" and then redownload as I scroll.

Since your tableViewCells are getting reused, the image being downloaded doesn't match the cell of the original fetch request.

in your inner,inner block, you need to verify that the cell still corresponds to the the managedObject/photo/indexPath you think is does.

Misc:

- Your spinner is leaking memory.
- after `[spinner stopAnimating]` you probably want a `[spinner removeFromSuperview]`

Comment: Thanks, that's a great help. 

My spinner now looks fine although I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean about the tableViewCells being reused.

Do you mean that the cell itself is basically being reused from under me when I scroll?

Isn't cell copied into the block's scope and therefore won't change?

Comment: the cell is retained by the block.  the block itself gets copied.  The OS will reuse cells as you scroll for performance reasons.

Comment: So I'd want to call indexPathForCell:cell and then use that index path to assign the image to the cell before reloading it?